# Solve integral with implicit function

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate an intergral that includes an implicit function definition. In particular, the integral definition is something like:

```
 int(s*y(s), s, 0, x)
```

where y(s) is implicitly given as the solution to an equation that cannot be solved explicitly. For example: Some function with 2 variables `f(s, y(s)) = 0` where the MATLAB output of `solve(f(s, y(s)), s)` contains a RootOf symbol.

This is the error:

> Warning: The solutions are parametrized by the symbols: y = R_ intersect RootOf(z^13 - (6*x*z^11)/7 - z^2/7 - x/14 + 1/14, z) minus {0} > In solve at 190 In @(x)solve(psi_v_fun(x,y)-psi_c_fun(x,y)==0,y,'Real',true) In TNAM at 33 ans = y^2 - 0.5

Comment: What does MATLAB give you when you run the above `int()` command ?

Comment: This is what it gives: Warning: The solutions are parametrized by the symbols:
y = R_ intersect RootOf(z^13 - (6*x*z^11)/7 - z^2/7 - x/14 + 1/14, z) minus {0}
 
> In solve at 190
  In @(x)solve(psi_v_fun(x,y)-psi_c_fun(x,y)==0,y,'Real',true)
  In TNAM at 33 
 
ans =
 
y^2 - 0.5